# How to retrieve from Firebase based on current user

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, vuejs2

Here is the deal.
I am using VueFire and would like to retrieve data from a Firebase database I have set up. In there I have a node with users and each one is defined by a unique id. Also for every user I have an array with a cart full of items they would to purchase. To make it dynamic I am calling the reference in the firebase hook like so:

```
export default {
  firebase:{
      cart: app.database().ref('users')
  }, //and so on and so on
}
```

Instead of `.ref('users')` I want to retrieve the current user, using his unique id like so: `.ref('users/' + user.uid + '/cart')`
To get the current user uid I do the observer that is `firebase.auth().onAuthStataChanged(user=>{//code here})`
Problem is, since this is asynchronous, the firebase hook activates before the current user is retrieved. I have tried to simply call `firebase.auth().currentUser`, but this is also slow and unreliable to use. 
I am open to any kinds of suggestions!

Comment: You need to wire it up such that you bind the reference asynchronously, *after* `onAuthStateChanged` fires. You must wait for it to fire to accurately know the user id and whether or not a user is signed in.

Comment: I kind of had the same issue and I'm doing it with `firebase.auth().currentUser` like this:  

`users: this.$root.db.ref('users/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)`

I tried checking for `uid` on `created()` and setting it and then using `this.uid` instead of `firebase.auth().currentUser.uid` but that didn't work.  I'm looking for a better solution too if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

I made a solution that worked for my case and *might* work for yours.

What I did is attach value listeners when the user gets authenticated and then I turn them off when the user loses authentication.  With this method I'm only asking to retrieve user data if the user is actually authenticated.  Here's how I did it:

```
this.$root.firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if (user) {
    this.$store.dispatch('setUserUID', user.uid)
    // Listen for User Data
    let dataRef = this.$root.db.ref('/userdata/' + user.uid)
    let self = this
    dataRef.on('value', function(snap) {
        let value = snap.val()
        self.$store.dispatch('setUserData', value)
      })
  }
  else {
    // Stop Listening for User Data
    this.$root.db.ref('/userdata/' + this.$store.state.user.uid).off()
    this.$store.dispatch('setUserUID', null)
  }
})
```

Comment: In which hook should that go? Or maybe before `export default`? Because I need to attach the ref to the firebase binding.

Comment: You could create the VueFire binding manually as describe in its documenation when the user is authenticated.  So during `onAuthStateChanged` you check if there is a `user` and if there is you will do `vm.$bindAsObject('user', myFirebaseRef.child('user'))`  and then if there is not a user you can do `vm.$unbind('items')`

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got it. Thanks to @Daniel D for his tip on binding as an array or object. So as it turns out I don't have to do it in the firebase reference hook, I just have to bind it as array in the `mounted()` hook for example. I just declare an empty `cart: []` in data and then fill it like so:

```
<script>
import changeColorMixin from '../mixins/changeColorMixin'
import animateFunction from '../mixins/animationMixin'
import Firebase from 'firebase'
import app from '../firebaseApp'

export default {
 data(){
   return{
     isLoggedIn: '',
     cart: []
   }
 },
 methods:{
    changeColor: changeColorMixin,
    animateEntrance: animateFunction,
    promptLogin: function(){
    console.log('you need to login!');
},
chooseSize: function($event){
    $($event.target).parents().eq(2).addClass('chosen');
},
closeOrder: function($event) {
    $($event.target).parents().eq(2).removeClass('chosen');
},
makeOrder: function($event){
    var $this = this;
    Firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
        if(user){
            var cartRef = app.database().ref('users/' + user.uid + '/cart');
                var currentCart;
                cartRef.once('value', function(result) {
                    currentCart = result.val();
                    var size = $($event.target).html();
                    var name = $($event.target).parents().eq(2).attr('id');
                    app.database().ref('users/' + user.uid + '/cart/' + name + '/count').once('value', function(snap){
                        var count = snap.val();
                        if(count > 0){
                            count = count + 1;
                        }else{
                            count = 1;
                        }
                        cartRef.child(name).set({
                            size: size,
                            count: count,
                            name: name
                        });
                    });
                });
            }else{
                console.log('gotta login mate');
            }
        });
    }
},
mounted(){
Firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if(user){
    this.isLoggedIn = true;
        var cartRef = app.database().ref('users/' + user.uid + '/cart');
        this.$bindAsArray('cart', cartRef);
  }else{
    this.isLoggedIn = false;
  }
});
    this.animateEntrance();
    this.changeColor();
  }
}
</script>
```

As I said big thanks to @Daniel D

Comment: You're welcome.  Remember to vote up the comments that help you!  Thanks!

Comment: Don't have enough reputation, sorry